# declaring a return type on a constructor doesn't cause a compilation error

Tags: java, constructor, return-type

I was writing code in Java and, absent-minded, i typed at some point `public void BaseStation()` as the constructor to a `BaseStation` class. To my surprise, this did not cause a compile-time error and the program got to run. Why is that? Is there any reason for someone to have a return type to a constructor?

Comment: it becomes a ordinary method.

Comment: so it is valid to have a method of a class, that shares the same name with the class?

Comment: It's completely legal. It's just really bad style.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specifying a return type makes this a method, rather than a constructor. You can have a method with the same name as the class (though this conflicts the conventions and is bad for readability)

Answer (score 2):

No, the compiler simply thinks that you have written a method called `BasedStation` and does not interpret it as a constructor.

Answer (score -1):

This is a type of overloading in Java. You can also overload by changing the parameters of a method.